# Custom shipping method for a specific country based weight in one country

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Sorry I didn't try anything as I couldn't even get how to start but basically I am looking for a custom shipping method to work in one country alone. THe shipping company to work with have a working policy of delivering 7kg or less for 1usd in any part of City A, >7kg to <=10kg, 2usd in City A. And so on for other cities in the country.

Is there such a plugin with such flexibility on woocommerce 3.5.1 or how would one incorporate such a functionality with cash and online payment systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this plugin
[shipping for specific country](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oik-weightcountry-shipping/)

or here is the tutorial link for creating shipping 
[How To Setup WooCommerce Country Based Shipping](https://aceplugins.com/doc/advanced-shipping-for-woocommerce/how-to-setup-woocommerce-country-based-shipping/)